# how to retrieve data ordered by key inside unspecified key with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a snapshot for my reference in firebase like this:

```
"friendlist" : {
    "user1" : {
        "user3" : 1
    },
    "user2" : {
        "user1" : 0
    }
    "user3" : {
        "user1" : 1
    }
}
```

The explanation for the reference:

Every user has an unique id, i'm using user's id for their friendlist unique id. In example above i have 3 users and every user have his own friendlist. Inside their friendlist, there's other user's id that already be friend with him. If the value is `1`, the user already be friend. But when the value is `0`, the user is requesting to be friend.

My problem is:

How to get all user's friendlist's id which have `"user1"` with value 0 inside their friendlist? Can i do that in just one query?

I think i need to iterate through all friendlist and orderbykey for every friendlist and looking for `"user1"`. Or there's any good approach to do that?

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you next time tell a bit more about what you've already tried. Or at the very least specify what language/environment you're targeting.

But in JavaScript, you can get those users with:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/friendlist');
var query = ref.orderByChild('user1').equalTo(0);
query.once('value', function(usersSnapshot) {
    usersSnapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        console.log(userSnapshot.key());
    });
});
```

With the sample data you specified, this will print:

```
user2
```

You should add (and will get a warning about) an index for efficiently performing this query:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "friendlist": {
      ".indexOn": ['user1']
    }
  }
}
```

Without this index, the Firebase client will just download all data to the client and do the filtering client-side. With the index, the query will be performed server-side.

### A better data model

You'll likely want to search for any friend, which turns the index into:

```
      ".indexOn": ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

But with this structure, you'll need to add an index whenever you add a user. Firebase SDKs don't have an API to add indexes, which is typically a good indication that your data structure is not fitting your needs.

When using a NoSQL database, your data structure should meet the needs of the application you're building. Since you are looking to query the friends of `user1`, you should store the data in that format too:

```
"friendlist" : {
    "user1" : {
        "user3" : 1
    },
    "user2" : {
        "user1" : 0
    }
    "user3" : {
        "user1" : 1
    }
},
"friendsOf": {
    "user1": {
      "user2": 0,
      "user3": 1
    },
    "user3": {
      "user1": 1
    }
}
```

As you can see, we now store two lists:
* `friendList` is your original list
* `friendsOf` is the inverse of your original list

When you need to know who friended user 1, you can now read that data with:

```
ref.child('friendsOf').child('user1').on('value'...
```

Note that we no longer need a query for this, which makes the operation a lot more scalable on the database side.

### Atomic updates

With this new data model, you need to write data in two places when adding a friend relation. You can do this with two `set()`/`update()` operations. But in recent Firebase SDKs, you can also perform both writes in a single update like this:

```
function setRelationship(user1, user2, value) {
    var updates = {};
    updates['friendList/'+user1+'/'+user2] = value;
    updates['friendsOf/'+user2+'/'+user1] = value;
    ref.update(updates);
}
setRelationship('user3', 'user4', 1);
```

The above will send a single command to the Firebase server to write the relationship to both `friendList` and `friendsOf` nodes.